# Parse Push: Sound Option in Settings Not There

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, push-notification

How do I make notifications have sounds or custom sounds?
Under the [Settings app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6EF8.jpg) there is no option to toggle sound when you receive a notification.

Here is my AppDelegate.swift:

```
import UIKit
import Parse

@UIApplicationMain class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    if application.applicationState != UIApplicationState.Background {
        // Track an app open here if we launch with a push, unless
        // "content_available" was used to trigger a background push (introduced
        // in iOS 7). In that case, we skip tracking here to avoid double
        // counting the app-open.
        let oldPushHandlerOnly = !self.respondsToSelector(Selector("application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:"))
        let noPushPayload: AnyObject? = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]
        if oldPushHandlerOnly || noPushPayload != nil {
            PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
        }
    }


    let userNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert; UIUserNotificationType.Badge; UIUserNotificationType.Sound;

    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: userNotificationTypes, categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    // Register for Push Notitications
    if application.applicationState != UIApplicationState.Background {
        // Track an app open here if we launch with a push, unless
        // "content_available" was used to trigger a background push (introduced in iOS 7).
        // In that case, we skip tracking here to avoid double counting the app-open.

        let preBackgroundPush = !application.respondsToSelector("backgroundRefreshStatus")
        let oldPushHandlerOnly = !self.respondsToSelector("application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:")
        var pushPayload = false
        if let options = launchOptions {
            pushPayload = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] != nil
        }

        if (preBackgroundPush || oldPushHandlerOnly || pushPayload) {
            PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
        }
    }

    if application.respondsToSelector("registerUserNotificationSettings:") {
        let userNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert; UIUserNotificationType.Badge; UIUserNotificationType.Sound;
        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: userNotificationTypes, categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    } else {
        let types = UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge; UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert; UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound;
        application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)
    }

    Parse.setApplicationId("0Es3NKun77RZtKbM2RfyGK8m39eBp6CuKlIXcpIc",
        clientKey: "rfLGlmOTbPTM4HrGfcFaDWxseN4H64ydgx2TRFMJ")



    let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Alert, categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)

    return true
}



func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}


func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
    installation.saveInBackground()
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    if error.code == 3010 {
        print("Push notifications are not supported in the iOS Simulator.")
    } else {
        print("application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@", error)
    }
}

func application(application: UIApplication,  didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],  fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    if application.applicationState == .Inactive {
        PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
    }
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
    if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive {
        PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
    }
}}
```

I also have a custom sound in the project called sound.aiff and I use this JSON when I send out notifications.

```
{ 
  "alert": "sound", 
  "sound": "sound.aiff" 
}
```

After that no sound is played when the notification is received and there is also no sound option under the notifications tab in the Settings app.

Comment: When uploading the file, did you tick "add to target" ?

Comment: @AmbroiseCollon Yes, I have added it to the target and it still doesn't work.